# Как сгруппировать строки с одинаковыми значениями в Oracle и взять оттуда предпоследний элемент?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-key, oracle-apex

У меня есть две таблицы: SaleMan и SaleMap. Моя задача - вывести предпоследнюю покупку каждого человека (NAME и SALE_DAT). Людей (NAME) у меня несколько и есть повторяющиеся значения, даты покупок у каждого разные. Как можно сгруппировать каждого человека и найти у него предпоследнюю покупку? Вот фото этих двух таблиц:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эти две таблицы связывает Foreign Key Men_Pers_Code.Коротко о том, как выглядят данные (NAME и SALE_DAT):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот какой я пробовал писать код:

```
SELECT NAME, SALE_DAT 
FROM SALEMAN SN, SALEMAP SP
WHERE SN.MEN_PERS_CODE = SP.MEN_PERS_CODE AND
SALE_DAT = (SELECT MAX(SALE_DAT) FROM SALEMAP, SALEMAN WHERE SALE_DAT < (SELECT MAX(SALE_DAT) FROM SALEMAP))
ORDER BY NAME;
```

Однако данный запрос мне выводит одно предпоследнее значение SALE_DAT из всей таблицы вообще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подзапрос идет по всей таблице и, соответственно, выбирается вторая наипозднейшая дата из всей таблицы.

Можно его как-то ограничить (заодно пропишем join явно):

```
SELECT sn.name, sp.sale_dat
FROM saleman sn
     JOIN salemap sp on sn.men_pers_code = sp.men_pers_code
WHERE sp.sale_dat = (
           SELECT MAX(sp2.sale_dat)
           FROM salemap sp2
           WHERE sp2.men_pers_code = sp.men_pers_code -- по тому же человеку
                 AND sp2.sale_dat < (
                     SELECT MAX(sp3.sale_dat)
                     FROM salemap sp3
                     WHERE sp3.men_pers_code = sp2.men_pers_code
                 )
      )
```

Возможно, будет легче и быстрее для этой цели использовать [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/ROW_NUMBER.html#GUID-D5A157F8-0F53-45BD-BF8C-AE79B1DB8C41):

```
SELECT sn.name, sp.sale_dat
FROM (
    SELECT men_pers_code, 
           sale_dat, 
           --выбираем номера дат по порядку
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY men_pers_code ORDER BY sale_dat DESC) as rn
    FROM salemap
) sp JOIN saleman sn on sn.men_pers_code = sp.men_pers_code
WHERE sp.rn = 2
```

Должно сработать, только возникает вопрос что должно произойти если у человек две последние покупки в один день? Например, если четыре последние покупки: 01.04, 01.04,  01.03 и 01.03

Первый запрос проигнорирует обе последние покупки и выведет дважды 01.03. Дублирование можно исправить группировкой. Если же нужно выбирать 01.04, то переделать его будет сложно, нужно будет добавить проверку на количество.

Второй запрос, наоборот выведет 01.04. Если это неправильно, то вместо `ROW_NUMBER` нужно  использовать [`DENSE_RANK`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/DENSE_RANK.html#GUID-BB66F574-09DF-4594-87A4-ABD83E8DC3FE). Также потребуется сгруппировать записи, т.к. `DENSE_RANK` вернет 2 для обеих записей на 01.03

Comment: Спасибо большое, запрос сработал!

Comment: Только вот хочу задать вам вопрос: зачем вы соединяете две таблицы в первом запросе, они же итак связаны по внешнему ключу. Или вы хотите просто упростить процесс?

Comment: @РэмКудусов Пожалуйста! Я просто перенес условие из WHERE в JOIN для упрощения чтения. Так сразу видно как таблицы связаны между собой и какие условия относятся к ограничениям. На практике, условия в WHERE редактируются чаще чем JOIN'ы и, если условия будут смешаны, то есть риск при редактировании «потерять» связку таблиц. Но вообще это дело вкуса.